# Send Jquery Variable to Php Timthumb for resizing

Tags: php, jquery

Im trying to send a variable ( url of an image ) from a jquery script ... to a php string.

i need the show.showimage to be proccesed with timthumb "resizeimagenoecho( $value, 64, 64, auto, 2 )"

```
jQuery('.dj_name').html(show.dj_name);
                    jQuery('.show_name').html(show.show_name);
                    if (show.show_image) {
                        jQuery('.show_image').attr('src',show.show_image).show();

                        $.post('http://www.digitalark.ro/dieselfm/wp-content/themes/vice/p_player_trance.php', 'val='+ show.show_image, function (response) {

   });

                    } else {
                        jQuery('.show_image').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
            curr_show_info();
            setInterval(curr_show_info,60000);

</script>

<?
$value = $_POST['val'];
$resizedimg = '<img class="resizedimg" src=" ' . resizeimagenoecho( $value, 64, 64, auto, 2 ) . ' "/>';
echo ($resizedimg);
?>
```

Im not sure im on the right track .. hmmm..

Thanks

Comment: What is your question and what is the value of show.show_name?

Comment: show.showname is an imageurl ... and i need to use it outside the javascript .... in php..... $resizedimg = '<img class="resizedimg" src=" ' . resizeimagenoecho( $value, 64, 64, auto, 2 ) . ' "/>';
echo ($resizedimg);  ... where $value is show.show_name

Comment: You should update your question to make it clear what you're expected result is and what the current problem is.